# Unsupported style property aria-label. Did you mean ariaLabel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I am trying to perform an add or edit function (pressing the edit or add button on the Material-UI table I get the following warning. I have tried to upgrade to the most recent version.  "material-table": "^1.63.1", but that didn't seem to help prevent the warning. Please let me know if I am missing a setting or if this is a bug within Material-UI.

```
Warning: Unsupported style property aria-label. Did you mean ariaLabel?
    in input (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in ForwardRef(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by ForwardRef(Input))
    in ForwardRef(Input) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)))
```

Comment: Looks like you have an input with a "aria-label" attribute instead of "ariaLabel" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ . What's being rendered in the table?

Comment: It's probably something in your code...just search your project for `aria-label` and replace it with `ariaLabel`

Comment: My grep results only show it in the node_modules directory.  Based on some debugging it appears to be triggered only on page load. After the page load and I press the edit button, the warning is triggered. If I perform another edit function no warning appears. Very strange. Thanks for the tips.